# What are multiple screen components in App Inventor?

Tags: android, app-inventor

I've been going through App Inventor for Android by Jason Tyler.

He says: "*Currently, App Inventor does not support multiple screen components. This is a limitation that many find frustrating*."

So, what I couldn't find anywhere is: "What are multiple screen components."
Could someone give and example, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at some old information, most probably for App Inventor Classic.

Multiple screens already have been introduced in 2013, see also the [tutorials about multiple screens](http://explore.appinventor.mit.edu/ai2/tutorials?field_tutorial_type_tid[]=73) and [The recommended method of switching screens in App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/manager.php)

For current **App Inventor 2** tutorials let me recommend you to do the [MIT tutorials](http://explore.appinventor.mit.edu/ai2/tutorials) and the [tutorials from appinventor.org](http://www.appinventor.org/)